# Facebook-like notification when a content type is modified

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I am dealt with a serious issue as I am told to make a facebook-like notification process in my website. I am working in `drupal 7` and i have a particular content type `event`.When an `event` is subscribed and if anything is modified on a particular `subscribed event`,a `notification` has to be shown.Is there some `contributed modules` that may help me..??Or should i be using `ajax` that is to be called at timely intervals.Could some one please help me ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: ever heard of websockets ?

Comment: you can use socket.io and nodejs.. just saying.

Comment: yes.heard of it.somthing like a TCP protocol rit.??but i nvr digged deep in that area.

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code